# How to define the Node.js status code without exiting immediately?

Tags: node.js, exit

In Node, the [`process.exit(code)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_exit) method allows one to exit with the `code` status code.

However, what I am looking for is a way to define, under some condition that are not temporally defined, the status code with which the process will exit, without exiting immediately.

How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `process`'s [`exit` event](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_event_exit).

Even though it has the same name as the method, an `exit` handler will not be called recursively if you call `process.exit` from within:

```
var code = 0;
// ...
code = 1
// ...
process.on('exit', function() {
    process.exit(code);
});
```